# fatal error: stdio.matrixVector: File or directory not found

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile a C method

```
#include <stdio.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit.matrixVector>

void  myMethod(double vector[], double matrixVector[])
{
    int n = sizeof(matrixVector)/sizeof(double);
    gsl_matrix *X = gsl_matrix_calloc(n, 3);
    gsl_vector *Y = gsl_vector_alloc(n);
    gsl_vector *beta = gsl_vector_alloc(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ....
    }

....

}
```

but I get this error

```
fatal error: stdio.matrixVector: File or directory not found
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: I'm using `-gcc myprog.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- all the include are wrong

```
#include <stdio.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit.matrixVector>
```

should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit.h>
```

note that 3 `include` need the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), make sure to have installed it before compile the code

2- in the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

you have to declare `i` outside of the loop (if you aren't in C99 mode).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `#include` lines, you've replaced all of the `.h` suffixes with `.matrixVector` in what I assume was a bulk replace for the rest of the file.

Change:

```
#include <stdio.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.matrixVector>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit.matrixVector>
```

To:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit.h>
```

Comment: `fatal error: gsl/gsl_matrix.matrixVector: No such file or directory` i have already installed `libgsl0-dev` and `libgsl0-dbg`

Comment: Yes, it needs to be `.h` on the end, like I said.